# CakePHP 3 - Cake trying to validate notEmpty for some reason

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My table is throwing a default "notEmpty" validation error, even though I have not written any validation of the sort.

Basic validation in my Table class:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    return $validator->requirePresence('my_field', 'create', 'Custom error message');
}
```

Data being set:

```
['my_field' => null]
```

As far as I can tell from the docs, this should not fail validation.

> Key presence is checked by using array_key_exists() so that null values will count as present.

However, what is actually happening is that validation is failing with a message:

```
'my_field' => 'This field cannot be left empty'
```

This is Cake's default message for the `notEmpty()` validation function, so where is it coming from? I want it to allow the null value. My database field also allows NULL.

**Edit**

I have managed to solve the issue by adding `allowEmpty()` to the validation for that field. This would, therefore, seem to show that Cake assumes that if your field is required you also want it validate `notEmpty()` by default, even if you didn't tell it so.

This directly contradicts the documentation line I showed above:

> Key presence is checked by using array_key_exists() so that null values will count as present.

So does the documentation need to be updated, or is it a bug?

Comment: can you please share your model coding?

Comment: The validation error occours because fields are by default not allowed to be empty, which however has nothing to do with whether their presence is required, that's two different rules. It may help if the docs would point out that empty fields are not allowed by default.

Comment: Yes, I understand how the two methods work, but the documentation needs to say that. I think it would be better for Cake to be less assuming, however, and not enforce the `notEmpty` rule without telling you.

Comment: As I said, it would probably help if the docs would make the default behavior more clear. You may want to open an issue [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not mentioned in the Cake 3 documentation, required fields are not allowed to be empty by default, so you have to explicitly state that the field is required **and** allowed to be empty.

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    return $validator
        ->requirePresence('my_field', 'create', 'Custom error message')
        ->allowEmpty('my_field', 'create');
}
```

Comment: You still seem to confuse this a little, this has nothing do with whether a fields presence is required, the "not empty by default" behavior applies to all fields, even to the ones that are not required.

Comment: @ndm No I understand it, but someone running into this same problem might like an answer in the context of getting the required field to allow null (as was the topic of the question I posted). I know both rules are separate and not related. In any case, perhaps it would be better if Cake allowed empty by default so that the application can define its own rules, rather than having to be aware of, and change, the rules Cake enforces for you by default.

Answer (score 0):

This had me stumped for a while. The default behaviour is not at all intuitive. Here's some code that applies conditional validation on an array of scenarios coded as `[ targetField, whenConditionalField, isConditionalValue ]`

```
public function validationRegister()
{
    $validator = new Validator();

    $conditionals = [ ['shipAddress1','shipEqualsBill','N'], ['shipTown','shipEqualsBill','N'], ['shipPostcode','shipEqualsBill','N'] ];
    foreach($conditionals as $c) {
        if (!is_array($c[2])) $c[2] = [$c[2]];
        // As @BadHorsie says, this is the crucial line
        $validator->allowEmpty($c[0]);
        $validator->add($c[0], 'notEmpty', [
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'on' => function ($context) use ($c) {
                return (!empty($context['data'][$c[1]]) && in_array($context['data'][$c[1]], $c[2]));
            }
        ]);
    }

    return $validator;
}
```

So, in this case, if the user selects that the Shipping Address is not the same as the Billing Address, various shipping fields must then be notEmpty.